# Android Buttons adding functionality

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created some buttons in XML and I have method that will onClick open a URL. How do I link this method to my button so that on tap/onClick it will call the method.

Here's the method code:

```
    public void openResource() {
     Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://librarywales.org");
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

And I have created an instance of my XML Button in the onCreate method:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button libButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
}
```

How do I add that method to the libButton instance?

I have now solved the above issue with the help of 'vins' but when I run this application on the AVD and click on a button it pops up with an android message box saying. 'Unfortunately, ApplicationName has stopped working.'

Anyone know why this is?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Button libButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    libButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button OtherButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    OtherButton.setOnClickListener(this);


   }

 @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1: openResource();
                           break;
    case R.id.button2: //do something for second button...

     default : break;
         }
```

Comment: what would the default statement be for this? Thanks by the way

Comment: default is just break; and dont forget to add import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

Comment: the emulator only responds to me selecting the first button. Is this because of the line of code
`Button libButton =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);` because that libButton is assigned to the id.button1

Comment: For second or whatever other buttons also you have to set the listener like you did for libButton.setOnClickListener(this); after getting its ID from findviewbyid(). Then you'll be able to catch the onClick event of that button. If you dont setOnClickListener , then if you click that particular button android wont sense that. I have updated it

Comment: Ahh right yes the logic has just hit me. Thank you for your patience vins four days into android apps!

Answer (score 1):

Add this after your button declaration

```
 libButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //open resource method call here...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
android:onClick="openResource"
```

In your xml file's button's property.

something like,

```
<Button
      android:id="@+id/button1"
      .
      .
      android:onClick="openResource"
      />
```

Note that this feature only is available on Android 2.1 (API Level 7) and higher

Comment: I thought of doing this just wasn't sure if it was more common practice to code into in the main application code. Thank you

Comment: Android already provide a nice way to handle `onClick()` method of a View, itself of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many buttons with in the page you can use button.setOnClickListener(this);

And override the OnClick() method within the method use Switch statement to match Which View has been selected.It's optimized and efficient way....

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button libButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


libButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{           
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.button1){
           Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://librarywales.org");
           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
           startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: thanks for this but there's an error with onClick(View v) it doesn't like the fact there's an @Override present.

Comment: also when I run this in the emulator it says Unfortunately, The Application has stopped. :/